# Passing a generic Promise to xstate's invoke

Tags: javascript, xstate

im trying to create a generic http state handler with xstate and Vue.

I have the following function:

```
makeRequest (a,b) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post(a,b // and some other code
        })
            .then(res => {
                return resolve(res)
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            return reject(err)
        })
    })
}
```

I want to make a generic promise as an [xState invoke service](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/communication.html#the-invoke-property) that will look somethings like this:

```
sendRequest: (promise) => {
  return promise
  }
```

which will receive makeRequest for example as an argument and will properly execute with xstates invoke, so it will be generic and I can pass every function that will return a Promise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you wrapping your `axios` call with a new Promise, as it's already returning a Promise?

Comment: Because I want to pass arguments to the function so the call will be dynamic, sorry, is this not the way to achieve this?

Comment: If you already have a promise (like the one from axios), there is no need to create a new promise. It is an antipattern.

Comment: secondly if `sendRequest` is going to receive a function like `makeRequest`, then why call that parameter `promise`? It is not a promise, but a function.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks for the tip I will change that. Any idea about the general problem I presented ?

Comment: I used promise because xstate recieves only promises (and some others but not functions) as invokables to my understanding

Comment: A promise is not an "invokable". A *function that returns a promise* can be invoked. It's really unclear what you mean by "*a generic promise*", where `sendRequest` appears in your xstate machine, and why it takes a `promise` as its argument

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you know maybe how to implement a generic function like you described that will receive a function and function parameters as arguments?